# To get Assigned Task to user Group name by API for HTML forms in Ektron

Tags: ektron

I am working in Ektron 9.0.
I could add a user group to Assign Task To while adding an HTML form in Ektron.
But I could not read the same property by Framework API .

FormData formData = frm.GetForm(dataTool.Id);//To get the form

This is my code.I could not find a property for Form for Assigned Task To.
My requirement is to get the user group name of the assigned task to in HTML form

Is there any other way to do this ? Am I doing something wrong ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tasks are independent of Forms; the two are just associated by the Form ID. What you've seen in assigning tasks to a group is just a shortcut. If you want to get tasks, you use the TaskManager.

Something like this should get all tasks associated with a Form with an ID of 12345.

```cs
var TaskCRUD = new Ektron.Cms.Framework.Settings.TaskManager();
var criteria = new TaskCriteria();
criteria.AddFilter(TaskProperty.ContentId, CriteriaFilterOperator.EqualTo, 12345);
criteria.PagingInfo = new PagingInfo();
criteria.OrderByDirection = EkEnumeration.OrderByDirection.Ascending;
criteria.OrderByField = TaskProperty.DueDate;
var TaskList = TaskCRUD.GetList(criteria);
```